# Suggestion for Design a Dynamic Data Entry Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-data

I want to create a dynamic data entry form based on this circumstance:

user can create a form and add to this form any number of fields with different accepting data types(such a field for text and another for currency and...).this fileds also can custom validation on them.

what is your efficiet idea about designing my tables in database any best way to implement this in c#.

*(I don't want whole code please just say your ideas and if code needs please write psudo code)*

thanks my friend

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to create a base form that handles CRUD operation ,and create some custom controls that have special property ,like fieldname ,fieldlength,caption,... showing a table in tree view that user can drag and drop field from treeview to design sheet can be good idea,
in save or delete or update operation you can read all related fields in form ,and affect proper operation on database

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ASP.NET for the front end:

First, you build custom controls for each data type in your dynamic data entry form. These custom controls need to encapsulate pre-defined validations (i.e., required field validation, regex validation, data type validation, etc.) and even support custom validation if you want to cover lots of data validation scenarios.

Then, you defined the meta data that drives the dynamic data entry form in typically database or xml. The meta data should define the data type of each field and what validations each field needs to have.

Finally, you build the data entry form dynamicly using the meta data and the corresponding controls. For ASP.NET, this is usually done at the Init stage of the page.

For the design, there's good articles here: [Creating Dynamic Data Entry User Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479330.aspx).

For the custom controls, please take a look of [XField Suite](http://xnodesystems.com/Products/XField/Default.aspx). These are controls I wrote to make building rich dynamic data entry form easy for developers.